# Java URL hangs and never reads in Website

Tags: java, url

I am trying to read in a website and save it to a string.  I'm using this code below which works perfectly fine in Eclipse.  But when I try to run the program via the command line in Windows like "java MyProgram", the program starts and just hangs and never reads in the URL.  Anyone know why this would be happening?

```
URL link = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));
            //InputStream in = link.openStream();
            String inputLine = "";
            int count = 0;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                site = site + "\n" + inputLine;
            }
            in.close();
```

...

Comment: Something may be restricting the program from accessing the internet. Try pinging a website via command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you are behind a proxy, and Eclipse is automatically adding settings in to configure this.

If you are behind a proxy, when running from the command prompt, try setting the `java.net.useSystemProxies` property.  You can also manually configure proxy settings with a few network properties found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) (`http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`).

Comment: +1 - note that Eclipse doesn't necessarily use the same proxies as a Java application run from the command line.

Comment: I tried setting System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true"); in the code but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered such a problem and found a solution.
Here my working code:

```
// Create a URL for the desired page
URL url = new URL("your url");
// Get connection
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds connectTimeout
connection.setReadTimeout(5000 ); // 5 seconds socketTimeout

// Connect
connection.connect(); // Without this line, method readLine() stucks!!!
// because it reads incorrect data, possibly from another memory area

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String str;

while (true) {
   str = in.readLine();
   if(str==null){break;}
   listItems.add(str);
}

// Closing all
in.close();
isr.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: some explanation as how it is working will help to know the cause of problem.

Comment: Timeout is a good idea. Btw do you think if there's any chance of a program to get stuck into while loop endlessly with your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

If that's all your code is doing, there's no reason it shoudln't work from the command line. I suspect you've cut out what's broken. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String site = "";
    URL link = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));
    //InputStream in = link.openStream();
    String inputLine = "";
    int count = 0;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        site = site + "\n" + inputLine;
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(site);
}
```

works fine. Another possibility would be if you're running it in Eclipse and from the command line on two different computers, and the latter can't reach http://www.yahoo.com.